# Что будет, если подключить одну dll два раза?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

[image: Dll]

Что будет если один *.exe загрузит одну и ту же *.dll два раза?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как написано в документации, при первом вызове `LoadLibrary()`, dll будет загружена в память процесса, и будет вызвана её функция `DllMain()` (с параметром DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH). При дальнейших вызовах  `LoadLibrary()` будет увеличиваться счётчик ссылок на эту dll. При вызовах `FreeLibrary()` счётчик ссылок будет уменьшаться, пока не станет равным нулю - тогда снова вызовится `DllMain()` (с параметром DLL_PROCRSS_DETATCH) и библиотека будет выгружена из памяти процесса.

Comment: @LShadow77 достойно ответа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Официальная документация https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya говорит что:

> If the specified module is a DLL that is not already loaded for the calling process, the system calls the DLL's DllMain function with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value.

Если данная библиотека ещё не была загружена, будет вызвана функция DllMain этой библиотеки с параметром DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).

Система отслеживает количество ссылок на каждый модуль индивидуально для каждого процесса. Вызов LoadLibrary увеличивает счётчик ссылок. Вызов FreeLibrary или FreeLibraryAndExitThread — уменьшает. Система выгружает модель когда счётчик доходит до нуля или при завершении процесса (невзирая на значение счётчика).

Таким образом, повторная загрузка библиотека не приведёт ни к каким негативным последствиям. Не будет ни ошибки, ни перерасхода памяти.

Сделано так потому, что кроме самого процесса, загрузить какую-нибудь dll, особенно системную, могут ещё и другие dll, загруженные этим процессом. Или это могут независимо друг от друга несколько статически прилинкованных библиотек.